# Android - Parabolic motion

Tags: android

I have a moving object in surface view it stat moving from fixed location.

I need set to it to be move like parabolic way ..my object drawn like using x and y so I do

not know using that thread how to calculate the X and y plz help?

Answer (score 3):

The basic formula is:

y=x^2 + m

(m being the x offset)
(the 2 can be an even number higher that 2, but use 2 for now)

Your starting location has the coordinates y0, x0

So you first location is:

```
y = x0^2 + y0
```

For the next step calculate your x value like this

```
x = x0+(n*stepsize)
```

x0 is you initial x value (see above).
stepsize is the could of pixels offset to each step (simply use 1 for now)
n is the current step inside your drawing loop, like this: for(int n=0;n<100;n++)

then calculate your y value with this x value

```
y = x^2 + y0
```

**Major Edit:**

So i thought of another way to do what you're trying to do which is much simpler:

First you need to define your start (x0|y0) and end (x1|y1) coordinates.
Then use separate formulas to calculate the new position during the animation.

Calculate the distances

```
x0x1 = x1 - x0
y0y1 = y1 - y0
```

Define how many animation steps you want (let's say 20)
Devide the distances by this value and in each animation step add that step distance to the last coordinate.

Now to make the whole thing a parabola you'll have to split the distances not evently but logarithmical, at least at the start of the motion. But please try the former before attempting this.

This is a more numerical approach - i hope it helps.

Comment: I have these parameters srtting x y ending XY   length from xY need parabolic x y for this xy distence???

Comment: okay i tried... but that's as low level as i can think of it... You may want to refresh your maths knowledge here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola

Comment: Okay ... so you have basically two points and you want to find a parabolic path between the points. I'm not sure if you really want to use a parabola here. I'd go with simple circula motion. Curefitting isn't exactly my strongsuit (anymore)

Comment: @joso nice explanation given by you. The same I am looking for i need to move an icon in a circular path.starting from x =0 and y = Maxhight. Can you please give some hint/idea about it

Comment: well... circula paths are calculated by using x = x0 + r * sin(t) and y = y0 + r * sin(t), where x0 and y0 are your starting offset, r the radius of the circle and t the run variable that should go from 0 to 2pi in the step size you like. But you should really open another question for that...